# segmentation fault (core dumped) error in C on Linux

Tags: linux

I tried to run the following program to outpout bmp file using gcc compiler but it shows the error: segmentation fault(core dumped). I got an effort to solve this problem but it didn't change anything. 
Also, I would like to know any mistakes to occur error for opening new bmp image.
FILE             *infile;

```
FILE             *outfile;

BITMAPFILEHEADER  hf;          
BITMAPINFOHEADER  hInfo;       
RGBQUAD           hRGBpal[256];
```

Comment: Also, watch out for the size and endianness of `struct` members such as `hInfo->biSizeImage` which is of type `DWORD` stored in little-endian format.

Comment: Indentation *please*.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about differences between them.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading into unallocated pointers

```
fread(&hf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,infile);
fread(&hInfo,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,infile);
```

You need to allocate memory to these pointers when read into them

Edit: You need remove `&` from read if you plan to read into pointers allocated using malloc, as &hf will take up address of pointer variable hf not address of memory allocated in it

Otherwise as mentioned @user0042 just declare them as variables not as pointers so that there is not need to allocate memory to them

Comment: _"You need to allocate memory to these pointers when read into them"_ Or simply omit them being declared as pointers.

Comment: could you give me an example in detail? I can't got what you say

Comment: @kookoo Just write `BITMAPFILEHEADER hf;` and for `BITMAPINFOHEADER` accordingly.

Comment: If you define them as a `struct` not a pointer you will need to change every `->` to a `.` for example `hInfo->biSizeImage` to `hInfo.biSizeImage`